# Add EXTRA parameter to XMLHttpRequest Handler

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Following is the way I know for adding parameters to request handlers for XMLHttpRequest.

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function ABC() {
    if (request) {
            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.onreadystatechange = function() { handler(param1, param2); };
            request.send();
    }
}

function handler(param1, param2) {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            //do something on success
        } else {
            alert("Invocation Errors Occured");
        }
    }
}
```

That is fine and good. But, kindly look at the following code.

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function ABC() {
    if (request) {
            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.onreadystatechange = handler;
            request.send();
    }
}

function handler(evtXHR) {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            //do something on success
        } else {
            alert("Invocation Errors Occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Here, i'm calling the handler without any parameter, but i'm getting an object of type `XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent` in the `evtXHR` parameter of the code.
Now I have two questions.

1. How am I getting `evtXHR` parameter when I make a parameter-less call?
2. How to add a parameter along with `evtXHR` so that I still get the `XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent` object?

So, I want something like this:

```js
function handler(evtXHR, myParam) {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            //do something on success
        } else {
            alert("Invocation Errors Occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You aren't making a call. the XHR object is. The `handler` function is being called by the XHR object in response to receiving the event.
2. Don't try to pass it as an argument. Use a closure instead.

Such:

```
var myData = 1234;

request.onreadystatechange = handler;

function handler(event) {
     alert(myData); // Use myData from the wider scope instead of trying to pass it as an argument
}
```

Comment: I know that can be done, in-fact, I'm doing it already. Though I want to know if it can be done without global variables.

Comment: Yes. You put it all inside a function (e.g. the one that creates the `xhr` object). There's no reason for `myData` to be a global.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good work around! But there is no way to do something like I mentioned? Like pass an extra argument method to do this?

Comment: Not without changing the code for the XHR object (which is a browser internal function)

Comment: Could you include your comment about "putting it all in a function so that `myData` is not global" in your answer. I'll mark it as accepted answer.